# Animating an svg mask works, but only the first times

Tags: css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to create a transition effect using SVG masks and CSS. I got to the point where the transition effect is working correctly, but after a few times (usually 1 or 2, but it seems random) the effect stops working, and the transition is instantaneous. I've checked my code, and logged to check if there was an issue with the generated SVG, but it is correct, and no different from the first times when the effect works as expected.

This happens both in Firefox and Chrome.

I created a JSFiddle that reproduces this error: https://jsfiddle.net/nrm4fwg0/1/

```
function lerp(start, end, t) {
  return start * (1 - t) + end * t;
}
const noise = (visible, wasVisible, durationSeconds = 1, seed = 44, liminal = 0.1) => {
  const startOp = lerp(liminal * 2, 1 + liminal * 2, wasVisible?1:0);
  const endOp = lerp(liminal * 2, 1 + liminal * 2, visible?1:0);

  const slope = -1 / (liminal * 2);
  const startIntercept = (startOp - liminal) * -slope;
  const endIntercept = (endOp - liminal) * -slope;


  return `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewport="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <filter id="alpha-effect">
      <feFlood  x="0" y="0"
      width="100" height="100"/>
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3"/>
      <feComponentTransfer result="SMOOTH">
        <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="1 0.7 0.3 0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feTurbulence seed="${seed}" result="NOISE" type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.05" numOctaves="5"/>

      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="NOISE"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SMOOTH"></feMergeNode>
    </feMerge>

      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="${slope}" intercept="${endIntercept}">
            <animate
            attributeName="intercept"
            from="${startIntercept}"
            to="${endIntercept}"
            dur="${durationSeconds}s" />
        </feFuncA>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" 
        fill="blue" filter="url(#alpha-effect)"/>
</svg>
`;
};


let isCardVisible = true;
function toggleCard(){
    const card = document.querySelector('#card');
  const mask = noise(!isCardVisible, isCardVisible);
  isCardVisible = !isCardVisible;
 
  
  card.style['mask-image'] = `url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(mask)})`;
  card.style['-webkit-mask-image'] = `url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,${btoa(mask)})`;
  card.style['mask-size'] = 'cover';
  card.style['-webkit-mask-size'] = 'cover';
  card.style['mask-repeat'] = 'no-repeat';  
}

document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', toggleCard);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figure a solution, but i don't know the explanation, so if anyone has any idea on why this is happening, i would love to know.

Basically, I just had the id of the filter be random each time:

`` const id = `alpha-${Math.random()}`; ``

and then use that instead of the fixed `alpha-effect` i was using. Now, the effect will keep on working

Comment: Just an idea: browsers are comparing the data urls if a new one is set. If they are deemed identical, the update is aborted to gain performance. But maybe they only compare the start of the strings up to a certain length. In changing a part that is nearer to the start of the string, you get before the cutoff. The effect holds also true for base64-encoded strings. I tested that in your first version, the first differing character had position 927, and in the solution it was position 191.